# definition of bounded variation on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

That's the definition of *bounded variation* I know: a function $f$ defined on a real closed interval $[a, b]$ is said to be of *bounded variation* if 
$$\tag{1}V_a^b(f)=\sup\left\{\sum_{P} \lvert f(x_{j+1})-f(x_j)\rvert \ :\ P\ \text{partition of }[a, b]\right\}<\infty.$$

My question: Is the definition the same for an open interval?

Thanks.

Comment: Found this: http://books.google.com/books?id=J723k_YUWhwC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=bounded+variation+implies+bounded&source=bl&ots=ASJTEJM6xM&sig=H4EqL8zah4poXxxDiEjWd64DIbs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WJ7zUuLwPMiorgH9vIGYDQ&ved=0CIQBEOgBMAk#v=onepage&q=bounded%20variation%20implies%20bounded&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition cannot be applied verbatim to open intervals, since partitions (by their definition)   contain the endpoints $a,b$ at which $f$ is not defined. This very minor nuisance can be disposed of in two ways:

1. Take supremum over all finite sequences $a<x_1<\dots<x_n<b$.
2. Define $V_a^b f = \sup\limits_{a<c<d<b} V_c^d f$ where the variation on the right is already defined because $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$.

I would probably go with (2), because it's consistent with the way we often deal with open sets: exhausting them with compact subsets.

A related concept is *locally bounded variation* on $(a,b)$: this only requires $V_c^d f<\infty$ for all $c,d$ such that $a<c<d<b$; the supremum over $c,d$ might be infinite.